# Installing SpeckPaypal Module into ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am having issues with installing this module into ZF2 via composer. I have edited the composer.json file that comes with zend framework 2 but it won't install when I run the command php composer.phar install.

Here is what my composer.json file looks like:

`"name": "speckcommerce/speck-paypal",`

```
"description": "A generic module for adding PayPal support to a ZF2 application.",
"type": "library",

"keywords": [ 
   "zf2"    
],

"homepage": "http://github.com/speckcommerce/SpeckPaypal",
"authors": [ 
{
  "name": "Stephen Rhoades",
  "email": "steve@stephenrhoades.com",
  "homepage": "http://www.stephenrhoades.com"

}
```

],

"require": {

"php": ">=5.4",

"zendframework/zendframework": "2.*"

},

"autoload": {

```
"psr-0": {

   "SpeckPaypal": "src/"
},

"classmap": [
  "./"
]
```

}

The source can be found at: https://github.com/speckcommerce/SpeckPaypal

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to

```
composer require speckcommerce/speck-paypal:dev-master
```

from your project root. The `composer.json` from the SpeckPaypal Module won't help you there :D

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if you are still struggling with this; but it appears that speck's composer json is not quite correct.

The accepted structure for a ZF2 module leaves module.php outside the scope of the standard psr-0 autoloader; most modules define ./Module.php in their classmap section see https://github.com/zendframework/ZendDeveloperTools/blob/master/composer.json as an example.